# Separate database column for salt

Tags: hash, databases, salt

Is it advisable to store the salt in a separate database column or should we concatenate it together with the password? Is there any difference? I have come across implementations of both types.

Example of concatented salt used in wordpress hashing function.

```
$P$Bo3k0g.yPKzWx.xmABq/hCuGLLd7A20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't make a bit of difference.  The salt in no way needs to be kept secure.  There are arguably some very minor security advantages to it remaining secret (since it would provide some protection against cracking trivial passwords), but if your security is dependent on that, then your security is broken.

Additionally, the difference between being in the same column vs being in a different one is unlikely to make a bit of difference if the DB is compromised.  It might be minimally beneficial to put both in an encrypted column, but if they are two encrypted columns or one doesn't make much difference either.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's more of a performance question, basically which of these database schemas involves less overhead. Either way if the DB is compromised an attacker would be able to easily find the salt for each password hash. Since a salt just protects you from pre-compute attacks, but is needed for authentication, it's difficult and not really worth the effort to attempt to separate it from the password hash.